# Paypal Encrypted Button, encrypted value

Tags: php, curl, encryption, paypal

How do you get the value of the encrypted input on the dynamic paypal html form? My server side language is php.

Here is my html

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST" class="block">
<input name="'.Cart_Form_Cart::FORM_TRY.'" type="hidden" value="1" />
<input name="'.Cart_Form_Cart::FORM_ACTION.'" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
<input type="submit" class="form-submit blue-button pointer margin-top-20" value="Proceed to Checkout" />
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="**NEED THIS VALUE**" />
</form>
```

Here is my array of values and curl

```
$sendData = array(
     "METHOD" => "BMCreateButton",
     "VERSION" => "65.2",
     "USER" => "my-username",
     "PWD" => "my-pass",
     "SIGNATURE" => "my-sig",
     "BUTTONCODE" => "ENCRYPTED",
     "BUTTONTYPE" => "BUYNOW",
     "BUTTONSUBTYPE" => "SERVICES",
     "BUTTONCOUNTRY" => "GB",
     "BUTTONIMAGE" => "reg",
     "BUYNOWTEXT" => "BUYNOW",
     "L_BUTTONVAR1" => "item_number=$order_id",
     "L_BUTTONVAR2" => "item_name=purchase",
     "L_BUTTONVAR3" => "amount=$subtotal",
     "L_BUTTONVAR4" => "currency_code=GBP",
     "L_BUTTONVAR5" => "no_shipping=1",
     "L_BUTTONVAR6" => "no_note=1",
     "L_BUTTONVAR7" => "notify_url=http://www.abc.co.uk/paypal/ipn.php",
     "L_BUTTONVAR8" => "cancel_return=http://www.abc.co.uk/paypal/thanks",
     "L_BUTTONVAR9" => "return=http://www.abc.co.uk/paypal/return.php"
);

$url = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?';
```

Here is the curl call

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url.http_build_query($sendData));
$encrypt = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $encrypt;
```

UPDATE:

I tied everything to a variable in php then spit that variable out as text to the page. So for the line

```
$text .= '<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----'.$encryption.'-----END PKCS7-----" />';
```

How do I go about making '.$encryption.' start on a new line not indented in a value of the input?

Comment: You should have newlines after the cert header and before cert footer. `$text .= '<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----'."\n".$encryption."\n".'-----END PKCS7-----" />';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read official paypal docs here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0P017Q
You can use their official tools.

However I'm using modified version of this PHP class https://github.com/josephholsten/swaplady/blob/master/library/PaypalEwp.php
The code is old and hackish, but it works.

You need to create a certificate, upload your public certificate to paypal and get the cerficate ID they will generate after the upload. You also need their public certificate too. You configure an instance of that class with your certificate, private key, certificate ID and paypal public certificate.

*So basically what the code actually does is signing the data fields with your ceritificate, then with paypal public certificate.*

This is my version, i'm using it with symfony thus the prefixes and sfConfig, but other than that it's just PHP: https://gist.github.com/dincho/7d8d4ca4e1f5dede925b

Note in the example docs (in class source) the HTML field value is on new line and there is no indentation - **this is very important**!

Comment: Confused on how you're getting the cert id, and certificate. Are these related to my username/pwd and signature?

Comment: You generate your own certificate with openssl - [the documentation has an example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0P20E9) then you need to upload that certificate to paypal. After that when your certificate is listed you will see the cert ID.

Comment: I followed this but I'm getting a "We were unable to decrypt the certificate id." I know its right.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the new line in the value you were talking about. Please see my updated question